# Merging two datasets in Apache Pig

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, cloudera

i have two hbase input aliases:

```
X:
(a1,b2)
(a2,b2)
...
(an,bn)

Y:
(c1)
(c2)
...
(cn)
```

Now i want to "join" both aliases: the first line from X with the first line from Y. The final result should be:

```
RESULT:
(a1,b1,c1)
(a2,b2,c2)
...
(an,bn,cn)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Create a common join key, e.g. using REGEX_EXTRACT, then use the join opertation.

Answer (score 1):

A basic tenet of Pig is that order does not matter.  More generally, a relation is a *set* of tuples, not a *list* of tuples.  If order is important to your data, that should be reflected in the data itself, not by the manner in which it happens to be stored.

Nevertheless, a workaround does exist if you can guarantee that when you load your data Pig will process it in the order you want.  Use the `Enumerate` UDF from [DataFu](https://github.com/linkedin/datafu):

```
Xenum = FOREACH (GROUP X ALL) GENERATE FLATTEN(Enumerate(X));
Yenum = FOREACH (GROUP Y ALL) GENERATE FLATTEN(Enumerate(Y));
RESULT = FOREACH (JOIN Xenum BY i, Yenum BY i) GENERATE a, b, c;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using pig 0.11, then you could try to use the [`RANK`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/basic.html#rank) operator.  Something like:

```
XR = RANK X ;
YR = RANK Y ;
RESULT = JOIN XR BY $0, YR BY $0 ;
```

If you just do `RANK X` then it will give each line a unique sequential number.  If you do something like `RANK A by $0 DESC` then it opens up the possibility of not giving a unique sequential number.